# R object name to string using shortcut reference

Tags: r

I would like a function that can take an object name and convert it to a string in R.

but I would like to be able to call the object name using shorthand typing or other shortcuts like in for loops etc.

the purpose is so I can automatically assign graph and figure names from the objects that create them

I've tryed deparse(substitute()) but it dosnt seem to work when i use the shortcut list method to refer to a object.

this is how id like the function to operate

```
>all_mydata<-list(i_want_this_text_to_return_as_string=c(1,2,3,4),second_list=c("a","b","c"))
>object_name_as_string<-function(all_mydata[[1]])
>object_name_as_string
i_want_this_text_to_return_as_string
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. `i_want_this_text_to_return_as_string` already is a string, it is part of `names(all_mydata)`.

Comment: Do you need `names(all_mydata)[1]` ?

Comment: thank you names()[i] was the function i was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function I was looking for was names

```
> names(all_mydata)[1]
[1] "i_want_this_text_to_return_as_string"
```